# How can I view .tn files?

Tags: photos, mobile-phone

I copied photos from my LG env3 cellphone to my computer. The files are named with a group of numbers ending in `.tn`. When I try to open them I get the message "Invalid image." How can I view these files?

Comment: Like Marcin, I did a search and couldn't find anything. To make searching for an answer easier for yourself and for others, you should probably edit your post to include some more details.

Answer (score 5):

The Tracor Northern image file is a special proprietary format which is not suitable for normal image processing and must be converted to a different format entirely in order to be used by most systems. Programs which use the TN image format generally convert it to a separate and also proprietary IMG format which can be used on MAC and PC computers.

The TN format consists of 512 rows each consisting of 512 pixels and each pixel consists of 8 bits of grayscale color data.

Answer (score 1):

I did a couple searches on google and I can't find a .tn file type. There are .tn1, .tn?, and others starting with .tn but not .tn by itself. If you want to look at the various types that start with .th that I found you can look at the list here:

http://www.file-extensions.org/tn
[http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=^T](http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=%5ET)

Comment: [http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=^T](http://filext.com/alphalist.php?extstart=%5ET)

Answer (score 1):

Talked to verizon help desk.  You must send each picture to your personal e-mail account (from the phone) in order to be able to view them on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [Arlind's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/74094/how-can-i-view-tn-files/192450#192450), knowing something about the format would allow you to convert it with [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php):

```
  convert gray:mypic.tn mypic.jpg
```

you may have to play around a bit, depending on what this image really is, i.e.:

```
  convert -depth 8 gray:mypic.tn mypic.jpg
```

You also might have to use [interpolate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interpolate) or [clut](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#clut) arguments also.